# INDEX MATCH all values where date is within 7 days

Tags: excel

I am trying to list all my values from Column A where the date in column J is within 7 days. And whilst I want to show all values which meet this criterion I don't want duplicates to be shown.

I have multiple values which have dates that fall within the next 7 days:

```
Column A      Column J
1             9/11/2015
2             10/11/2015
3             11/11/2015
4             9/11/2015
```

I am using the following:

```
=INDEX(Opportunities!A:A,MATCH(TODAY() < 7,Opportunities!J:J,1))
```

However, this does not work and produces the error `#N/A`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear with you requirement (How does column I come to picture).

If i understand you correctly and you are doing this in excelsheet, this can be done in 2 simple steps.

1. in a new column, use formula = (J1 < TODAY() + 7) and drag it down, which will fill all rows with true or false. You can take all true values which will be rows with dates less than next 7 days
2. Goto data>remove duplicates> unselect all> select only column A and click ok